# Check if a required software is installed with maven

Tags: maven

I am writing a Java software that, for some optional operations, uses external programs. Namely, my program writes a `'.dot'` file, and uses `GraphViz` to compile that file to a `png` image.

Is it possible to check with `Maven` and in the case the required program is not installed print a warning message???

Comment: Check for existance of a file? See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-verifier-plugin/verify-mojo.html

Comment: The [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) has a [require-files-exist rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html). You can configure the plugin execution to not fail if the rule fails. I'm not sure if it prints a warning in that case or not though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [GMaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) to execute some Groovy code which checks whether GraphViz is installed.

For example this code will print a simple warning message if you run `mvn verify` without GraphViz installed:

```
<plugin>   
  <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>    
  <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>    
  <executions>        
    <execution>            
      <phase>verify</phase>            
      <goals>                
        <goal>execute</goal>            
      </goals>
      <configuration>        
          <source>            
           try {   
               def exitValue = "dot -?".execute().waitFor() 
               if(exitValue != 0)
                   println "Warning: dot is not installed!"       
            } catch (IOException e){
               println "Warning: dot is not installed!"       
            }  
          </source>    
       </configuration>
    </execution>            
  </executions>        
</plugin>
```

This does require the user to issue this specific maven command, although you can link it to a [different life cycle phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

However, if you want to deploy the application without requiring the user to use maven you probably want to issue the warning when an optional operation is requested.